# How can I add a UISearchBar to the top of a UITableView without using the tableHeaderView property?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uisearchbar

I want to add the search bar as a subview at the top of the table view and then push the rest of the content down but I want to do this without using the tableHeaderView property.

Thanks.

Comment: Why can't you use the tableHeaderView?!

Comment: Why can't you use UISearchbarController, which contains searchbar, and tableview both the way you want..

Comment: @paulrehkugler Because I'm doing this for a UICollectionView.

Comment: I'm going to need to do the exact same thing shortly! I'm using a collectionView too!

Answer (score 0):

Your only other option is to provide a container view (empty, clear, etc) as your primary view controller's view, then put the tableView inside it with constraints to the bottom and side, then insert a uisearchbar above it using a height constraint set to 0, and constrain the search bar to the top of the container view and the bottom of it to the top of the tableview. Keep an ivar to that search bar and the height constraint.

When you want to show the search bar, change the height of the constraint on the search bar height, it will drop down and push the tableview down.

Comment: Darn - that's what I figured I'd have to do. All right, thanks.